# AWS S3 Bucket Upload/Transfer with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, s3-bucket

I need to upload files to S3 and I was wondering which boto3 api call I should use?

I have found two methods in the boto3 documentation:

- http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file
- http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html

Do I use the client.upload_file() ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
session = Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('my_bucket').upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'hello.txt')
```

or do I use S3Transfer.upload_file() ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
session = Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region)
S3Transfer(session).upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'my_bucket', 'hello.txt')
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

.
.
.

possible solution...

```
# http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#examples
# http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object
# http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object

client = boto3.client("s3", "us-west-1", aws_access_key_id = "xxxxxxxx", aws_secret_access_key = "xxxxxxxxxx")


with open('drop_spot/my_file.txt') as file:
  client.put_object(Bucket='s3uploadertestdeleteme', Key='my_file.txt', Body=file)


response = client.get_object(Bucket='s3uploadertestdeleteme', Key='my_file.txt')

print("Done, response body: {}".format(response['Body'].read()))
```

Comment: If it's suitable, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy files. Use the `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` commands and it will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: You can also you Minio Client's `mc mirror` or `mc cp`  for the same [https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide#mirror](https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide#mirror)                Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the method on the client. They're the same, but using the client method means you don't have to setup things yourself.